# Creating <img> elements dynamically from FileSystem array

Tags: javascript, fs

I am trying to add `<img>` tags dynamically to my DOM using FileSystem to scan through my images folder.

My idea is to create one `<img>` element for each image I have in the "images" folder.

At the moment I am able **or** to create the `<img>` elements **or** to create an array with the filenames from the folder, but for a mysterious reason, when I join the pieces nothing works.

Someone could help me to figure out what is happening.

```
const imgContainer = document.getElementById("cover");

const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("class", "image-ctn");
imgContainer.appendChild(newDiv);

const addImage = (imgSource) => {
  const newImage = document.createElement("img");
  newImage.setAttribute("class", "face");
  newImage.src = `images/${imgSource}`;

  imgContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.appendChild(newImage);
};

//

const fs = require("fs");
const imagesPath = "images";
const pattern = ".jpg";

let imageArray = fs.readdirSync(imagesPath).filter((str) => {
  return str.includes(pattern);
});

imageArray.map((imageFile) => {
  addImage(imageFile);
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Deconstructed</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="menu">
        <nav>MENU</nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main class="main-container">
      <div id="cover"></div>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Mauris pellentesque
        pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Lectus
        proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum. Id diam maecenas
        ultricies mi eget mauris.
      </div>
    </main>
  
    <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use `fs` on the client side, you don't have access to the filesystem from a browser. Or is this meant to be an electron app?

Comment: All right! I got what you mean.

It is not an electron app. I am creating an animation where I will have one image sliced into many pieces (each slice is a different JPG file), and the pieces will reveal and move to the forefront while I scroll, forming the original image.

I wondered if using FileSystem to add the filenames into an array would make it easier, as I would not need to add every slice as a <img> hardcoded into the HTML file. The idea was just to grab the filenames and use them to define the path of the image src dynamically.

Would you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: That means that if I have the slices online, I can do the same job fetching the images from whatever service. Am I right?

Comment: This is a question of getting your data from the server to the client. What is your web server running? I hope node.js?

Comment: Yes, I am using node.js. But don't know exactly how to get that data into arrays so I can use it in the animation.

I can say I am lost.

Comment: 1. create an express route on the server where you serve the array (send it as JSON). 2. fetch that route from the client using `fetch`, 3. create a new img tag for each item in the array and add it to the document. Your life would a lot easier with react or similar, but it's totally doable without.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. Thanks a lot, Christian.